# Error:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, websocket

i am trying to post data to java rest service using asp.net .When i try calling service i get error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).

Please guide me in this i googled about it but found no solution.I have enabled my service to work in cors domain by adding code as mentioned below

in server application

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Status addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        dataServices.addEntity(employee);

        return new Status(1, "Employee added Successfully !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return new Status(0, e.toString());
    }

}
```

In asp.net application

```
      $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:9091/employeeservice/employee/create",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "id": 10,
                "first_name": "narayan",
                "last_name": "bhat",
                "email": "farah@gmail.com",
                "phone": "4545454545"
            }),
            error: OnErrorCall,
            success: OnSuccessCall,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });


        function OnSuccessCall(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }


        function OnErrorCall(response) {
            alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
        }
```

Please guide me in this i am new to asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to at-least try [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to Post & Get response from Rest APIs. This method is useful if you want to use Rest API code-behind.

I have been tried your way to call Rest Services some days ago and got 400 error from server. After that I tried [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) and it works for me.

You can make request & get response like below using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/):

```
var restClient = new RestClient("https://www.example.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Resource = "{version}/adduser";
request.AddParameter("version", "v1", ParameterType.UrlSegment);

request.AddParameter("email", "abc@example.com");
request.AddParameter("password", "abc123");

var response = restClient.Execute(request);

lblMessage.Text = response.Content;
```

Comment: i must use javascript to call rest services.

Comment: Did you tried to test rest service using https://www.getpostman.com??? I request you to add extension in chrome and test at-least once in Postman.

Comment: in post man its working correctly but its not working in asp.net ajax call

Comment: I faced same issue that you are currently facing. that's why I called Rest Service from code behind using RestSharp. I think you have to find out similar to RestSharp which can do same thing at client side.